# yii: select sum using query builder

Tags: yii

I try to execute a simple query like this:

```
$tot = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('sum(field)')
                ->from('products')
                ->where('id = ' . $id)
                ->queryRow();
```

But $tot return me null value.

Comment: your code looks fine, have you double checked your column name, table name, $id value? how are you checking the value of $tot?

Comment: try with `queryScalar()`

Comment: Use queryScalar() instead of QueryRow()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to add an alias to your sum, so something like this might work:

```
$tot = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('sum(field) as mySum')
    ->from('products')
    ->where('id = ' . $id)
    ->queryRow();
```