# yii how to find a sum from a db table?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hello everyone and thanks for reading

I have two tables ; 
1st table is the main table and its where i have the costs ,

the 2nd table is a a table where i have the users associated to those costs .

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to achieve the following ; 
creating a yii STAT query that returns the sum of all the costs for a specific user. 
This is what i did in mysql and i would like to convert it to yii format ;

```
    select sum(cost) from tbl_bridge_contract a
join tbl_employer_contract b using(id_employer_contract)
where a.user_id=4
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query

Comment: And for query builder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689406/yii-select-sum-using-query-builder

Comment: Iv seen those pages but iam not looking for the query builder but a way to write the relation and than somehow calling the relation to retrive the costs for the specific user

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your DB schema look like.. But let's assume we have two models(tables in database) - `Post` and `Comment`.

`Comment` refers to `Post`(`tbl_comment` has foreign key refers to `tbl_post`'s primary key). This means that `Post` HAS_MANY `Comment`s. According to this your `Post::relations` methods can look like:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'post_id'), // <-- post_id is FK in tbl_comment
        'countComments' => array(self::STAT, 'Comment', 'post_id'), // <-- the same as above, post_id is FK in tbl_comment
    );
}
```

then in any place(say in Controller) you an do this:

```
$post=Post::model()->findByPk(731);

var_dump($post->comments); // <-- dumps array of Comment-models, if any
var_dump($post->countComments); // <-- dumps number of related comments
```

And for sure you should read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query

I hope this helps.